# Sequence contains no elements error with linq

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, c#-3.0, dropdownlistfor

I'm having following LINQ code to find the DropDownList selected value

```
string txtnewrole = ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin").ToString();     
ListItem item = (from i in ddlRoleList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                 where ((ListItem)i).Value.Contains(txtnewrole)select i).First()as ListItem;
string roleid = ddlRoleList.Items.FindByValue(item.Value).ToString();
```

Linq statement giving me error, sequence contain no element, plz help me to correct this
, I tried with first default it returned me null, but in my DropDownList I'm having Admin text with value 2, I write this linq to get the value of admin, item value is null. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead `First()` And then check that item is not null. `First()` throw Exception if sequence doesn't contain elements, but `FirstOrDefault()` return null in this case.

Also notice that this code

```
string txtnewrole = ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin").ToString();
```

return something like `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem` I'm not sure that it is exactly what you want. Unless you override `ToString()` with extension method.

Comment: hi Daniel ,i tried with first default it returned me null,but in my dropdownlist im having Admin text with value 2,i write this linq to get the value of admin, item value is null ,how to achieve this

Comment: Check what return this `string txtnewrole = ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin").ToString();` I think you need `ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin").Text` and then `ListItem item = ddlRoleList.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => txtnewrole.Contains(x.Text))`

Comment: Or even better just use constant string "Admin" without manipulation with ListItems and it will not cause exception about @Siva Charan said.

Comment: And I mean `ListItem item = ddlRoleList.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Contains(textnewrole))` instead `ListItem item = ddlRoleList.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => txtnewrole.Contains(x.Text))`

Answer (score 2):

I want to add some more points to **@Daniel** answer.

1. While you use `ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin").ToString()`, there is a chance of `NULL` exception. If `ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin")` doesn't find it, it returns as **"NULL"**.
2. I don't see proper usage of `ddlRoleList.Items.FindByValue(item.Value).ToString();`. Here you are trying find by value once again and converting to string. Since you already found the `item` from the `Linq`.
3. You need to do is `item.Text`

If your better understanding, I wrote below code in a proper way for you:

```
String txtNewRole = String.Empty;
String roleId = String.Empty;

ListItem adminListItem = ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin");
if (adminListItem != null)
    txtNewRole = adminListItem.Text;

//ListItem item = ddlRoleList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Value.Contains(txtNewRole)).Select(i => i).FirstOrDefault();

//OR

ListItem item = ddlRoleList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value.Contains(txtNewRole));

if (item != null)
    roleId = item.Text;
```

Comment: I think better to use FirstOrDefault with predict instead Where with predict and then FirstOrDefault

Comment: ListItem adminListItem = ddlRoleList.Items.FindByText("Admin");then string rolid=adminListItem .value;

Comment: @shweta: Unfortunately, we don't know your requirement. But you understand on how you need to access the value. That's great.